# Text format in Data bricks (AZURE) to CSV

Tags: sql, azure, scala, csv, databricks

I have special characters and florigen language in data set.

when I run a SQL ( `Select * from table1` ), results are fine. I get in required format

eg output of SQL :

```
1 | 请回复邮件
2 | Don’t know
```

when the same is exported to CSV to my local machine those text changes to wired symbols

Exporter data :

```
1 | è¯·å›žå¤é‚®
2 | Donâ€™t know
```

How do I get the same format to CSV as in SQL?

Comment: check your local machine language settings

Comment: data to Azure is loaded from my Machine, the Raw data csv is having same format

Comment: tell the datatype you are using in azure

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin are you asking about the Column data type, I reading it using `spark.read.format`, and storing it as delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the data form Data bricks, Open the csv in notepad and `save as` under save select the Encoding option `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that UTF-8 encoding is used instead of ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252 encoding in the browser and editor.

It's better to utilise CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 and COLLATION utf8mb4 unicode 520 ci in the future. (A revised version of the Unicode collation is in the works.)

utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8, as it can support 4-byte utf8 codes, which are required by Emoji and some Chinese characters.

"UTF-8" outside of MySQL refers to all size encodings, thus it's basically the same as MySQL's utf8mb4, not utf8.

The data can't be trusted whether viewed with a tool or with SELECT. Too many of these clients, particularly browsers, attempt to compensate for erroneous encodings by displaying proper text even if the database is messed up. So, choose a table and column with some non-English content and work on it.

```
WHERE... SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl
```

**For correctly saved UTF-8, the HEX will be**

- 20 (in any language) for a blank area
- 4x, 5x, 6x, or 7x for English
- Accented letters in much of Western Europe should be Cxyy.
- Dxyy in Cyrillic, Hebrew, and Farsi/Arabic
- The majority of Asia uses Exyyzz
- Emoji, although some Chinese use F0yyzzww.

There are few fixes here: [Fixes for various Cases](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases)